# Testcafe testing IE on Windows Agent

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

What should I do with this error?

`ERROR Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.`

I got this error, when I try to run my test on ci on windows agent with that config:

[image: Agent config]

I try to run tests using command `testcafe ie ./src/*.spec.ts`.
Locally on Windows 10/IE 11 everything works well. What can cause problem with browser connection on agent?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft browsers, especially IE, are known for memory leaks in large JS scripts. It can cause browser crashes and hangs. We have an issue to restart a browser that became unresponsive: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1815, you can vote for it to show its importance and promote it for next development iteration.

**UPDATE AUG 2019**

Restarting browsers that don't respond was implement in a basic way.